typesetting prices
If I am typesetting a list of prices in French, is it acceptable to have the dollar signs aligned, which would create a wider space between the dollar sign and the price depending on the width of the price?

Use € instead of $ and they would be aligned ;-)

Acceptable... in what context?

The following formats are not the best ones :
Item A   12   $            Item A   $   12   
Item B   9    $    or      Item B   $    9
Item C   3456 $            Item A   $ 3456

Prefer :
Item A     12 $
Item B      9 $
Item C   3456 $


s/not the best ones/incorrect/

In English anyway, the dollar sign precedes the numeral, thus twelve dollars is rendered as "$12."

@PaulTanenbaum In France and most of European countries but the UK, the currency sign follows the numeral.

I know, @jlliagre, that’s why I mentioned it: I figured OP might be unfamiliar with the US convention.

@PaulTanenbaum Not sure. As the OP assumes the dollar sign won't be aligned if the width of the price value vary, I would guess he is more used to the US convention. He also talks about the space between the dollar sign and the price, and not the space between the price and the dollar sign.
